Renaming index (or is it index?) of pandas data frame fails persistently
This should be easy. I have a pandas data frame with Date as index; it is a period index.
When I plot the data, the legend mentions "Series" while I want it to show "Loan type".
I tried reset_index() and work from there, but 'Series' keeps popping up in the upper left corner.
Series  Loans  Loans Housing  ...  Loans Agriculture  Loans_Other
Date                          ...                                
2018Q2  100.0      58.058425  ...          14.498113     2.123517
2018Q3  100.0      58.366364  ...          14.439221     2.097073
2018Q4  100.0      58.588861  ...          14.343509     1.917685
2019Q1  100.0      58.693234  ...          14.189217     1.964198
2019Q2  100.0      58.936376  ...          14.187947     1.848167



What do you mean by "index (or is it index?)"?

What do you mean by "fails persistently"? You haven't written any code to rename the index, if I understand what you're saying correctly. Maybe a better title would be "How do I rename the column axis of a dataframe?"

Use rename_axis().
df.rename_axis("Loan type", axis=1)

